# Parameter Shows Up As Undefined when I pass it through the function

Tags: javascript, undefined

I've added breakpoints and it seems like the tempTime becomes undefined when I pass a variable. It becomes a number only when delayer is called. I don't know why it does that and I dont know how to fix it.

Javascript code

```
 var executionTime;
 var initialTime = localStorage.getItem("initialTime");


 if(initialTime == "null")
 {

 }
 else
 {
    var tempDate = new Date().getTime(); 
    executiontime = 30000-(tempDate- parseInt(initialTime, 10));
    if (executionTime<0) 
    {
    executionTime = 0;
    }  
    showPopUp(executionTime); //executionTime has a number when I call the function                        `//butshows up as undefined in the showPopUp function`
 }





 function showPopUp(tempTime){
  var initialTime = localStorage.getItem("initialTime");
  var executionTime = tempTime;

  if(initialTime== "null")
  {
    executionTime = 20000;
  }

  localStorage.setItem("initialTime", (new Date()).getTime());
  setTimeout(function() {
  showAlert();
  localStorage.setItem("initialTime", null);}, executionTime);
 }

  function delayer(){ 
  showPopUp(20000); //not undefined when called
  }

  function showAlert(){
   alert("Warning");
  }
```

Comment: `executiontime = 30000` I think you mean `executionTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
executiontime = 30000-(tempDate- parseInt(initialTime, 10));
showPopUp(executionTime);
```

you are using two different cases
capitalize your T in time
javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: oh lol. wow, how did i miss that? I was staring at the screen for an hour.